# Where's KeyLine defined?

Tags: opencv

According to https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d1/dd7/structcv_1_1line__descriptor_1_1KeyLine.html it should be defined in `line_descriptor.cpp` and `line_descriptor.hpp`, but I can't seem to find it there. Anyone know where the declaration and definition are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both definition and declaration of `KeyLine` are in `descriptor.hpp` at line 102, [see by yourself](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/line_descriptor/include/opencv2/line_descriptor/descriptor.hpp)

```
struct CV_EXPORTS KeyLine
{
 public:
  /** orientation of the line */
  float angle;

  /** object ID, that can be used to cluster keylines by the line they represent */
  int class_id;

  /** octave (pyramid layer), from which the keyline has been extracted */
  int octave;

  /** coordinates of the middlepoint */
  Point2f pt;

  /** the response, by which the strongest keylines have been selected.
   It's represented by the ratio between line's length and maximum between
   image's width and height */
  float response;

  /** minimum area containing line */
  float size;

  /** lines's extremes in original image */
  float startPointX;
  float startPointY;
  float endPointX;
  float endPointY;

  /** line's extremes in image it was extracted from */
  float sPointInOctaveX;
  float sPointInOctaveY;
  float ePointInOctaveX;
  float ePointInOctaveY;

  /** the length of line */
  float lineLength;

  /** number of pixels covered by the line */
  int numOfPixels;

  /** Returns the start point of the line in the original image */
  Point2f getStartPoint() const
  {
    return Point2f(startPointX, startPointY);
  }

  /** Returns the end point of the line in the original image */
  Point2f getEndPoint() const
  {
    return Point2f(endPointX, endPointY);
  }

  /** Returns the start point of the line in the octave it was extracted from */
  Point2f getStartPointInOctave() const
  {
    return Point2f(sPointInOctaveX, sPointInOctaveY);
  }

  /** Returns the end point of the line in the octave it was extracted from */
  Point2f getEndPointInOctave() const
  {
    return Point2f(ePointInOctaveX, ePointInOctaveY);
  }

  /** constructor */
  KeyLine()
  {
  }
};
```

Also it is unclear for me why did you think it should be in `line_descriptor.cpp` or `line_descriptor.hpp`